# Is there a list of equivalents between CSS Properties and HTML attributes?

Tags: html, css

I think that such a list would be useful, but I have been unable to find one

Comment: in what context? there aren't many presentational attributes in xhtml

Comment: @Daniel A. White: He said HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: This question made my eyes cross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about attributes, `bgcolor`, `color` and `align` are the only ones I can remember of.

If you look through [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) list you can check all the HTML4 tags. The ones you're looking for are almost all marked with *D*. I wonder why :)